# SelectedCells in DataGrid Returning Null

Tags: wpf, powershell, datagrid

I am trying to record the selected cells that a user selects in a WPF Datagrid. Using Powershell to do this, I am using the .SelectedCells property of the DataGrid object. When I use this against the DataGrid object, I write the results to host. Although I select cells in the GUI, nothing returns to the console. It does however, create blank spaces where values should go; thus, I know the event handler is working. I can successfully return a single value that is selected - more specifically, the current one - if I use the .CurrentCell property of the DataGrid Object (Go Figure). I have been looking for solutions on Google. Found plenty for C# and DataGridView. This is not a DataGridView, but a DataGrid from WPF.

**Code:**

```
$UI.DataGrid.Add_SelectedCellsChanged({

    # Returns nothing
    Write-Host $UI.DataGrid.SelectedCells

    # Returns current selected cell (which it should)
    Write-Host $UI.DataGrid.CurrentCell.'Column 1'
})
```

**Note:** I cannot use the 'Column 1' property with the SelectedItems property. I'm not entirely sure why, but I have reason to believe that is hindering me from returning results.

**Update:**

Problem lies within the selection mode in the XAML code. Once it is on "Cells", it doesn't allow me to select the column property. Once I changed the selection mode to "Row", I can easily select the column property. Investigating this now.